# glCreateProgram returns 0 after context restore

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I'm working on an Android OpenGL ES 2.0 program coded natively.  In my Activity's `onPause` method I call the `GLSurfaceView`'s `onPause` method, then call a native function which `glDeletes` all textures and shader programs.  In the Activity's `onResume` method I call the `GLSurfaceView`'s `onResume` method then call a native function which recreates all of the textures and shader programs.  The `GLSurfaceView` methods I mentioned are not overridden.  The textures seem to recreate without hassle (no `glGetErrors` after each call) but `glCreateProgram` is giving me zero and `glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkResults)` crashes the app.  This happens only with `onPause`/`onResume`, before then the shaders are created without a problem.  Any insight you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The shader compile / link functions have verbose error reporting facilities (glGetProgramInfoLog, glGetShaderInfoLog).  Check the output of those, and watch the logcat output for any messages from the driver.  What device, and what version of Android, are you using?

Comment: Samsung exhilirate, Android 4.0.4.  I'll check the output of those functions you mentioned but I think the problem must be further upstream if glCreateprogram is returning 0?  I don't recall seeing anything telling in logcat but I'll double-check when I work on it further tonight.

Comment: Oh, I misread your question.  Yes, glCreateProgram() returning zero is pretty strange, especially if other calls are succeeding.  Can you confirm that you're calling it in the GLSurfaceView's renderer thread after the Surface has been created?  My theory is that you're calling it in the wrong thread, which means the wrong context... and the other context is GLES 1.1, so your texture ops succeed but your shader ops fail.  Not sure why it would work on initial create but not after resume.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I'll study the code further tonight and see if I can pinpoint it further.